# Proving the Functor laws for free monads; am I doing it right?

Tags: haskell, monads, proof, free-monad

I'm having a bit of a hard time understanding how to prove the `Functor` and `Monad` laws for free monads.  First off, let me put up the definitions I'm using:

```
data Free f a = Pure a | Free (f (Free f a))

instance Functor f => Functor (Free f) where
    fmap f (Pure a) = Pure (f a)
    fmap f (Free fa) = Free (fmap (fmap f) fa)

instance Functor f => Monad (Free f) where
    return = Pure
    Pure a >>= f = f a
    Free fa >>= f = Free (fmap (>>=f) fa)

{-

Functor laws:
(1) fmap id x == x
(2) fmap f (fmap g x) = fmap (f . g) x

Monad laws:
(1) return a >>= f   ==  f a
(2) m >>= return     ==  m
(3) (m >>= f) >>= g  ==  m >>= (\x -> f x >>= g)

-}
```

If I understand things correctly, the equational proofs require appeal to a coinductive hypothesis, and it goes more or less like this example:

```
Proof: fmap id == id

Case 1: x := Pure a
fmap id (Pure a)
  == Pure (id a)   -- Functor instance for Free
  == Pure a        -- id a == a

Case 2: x := Free fa
fmap id (Free fa)
  == Free (fmap (fmap id) fa)  -- Functor instance for Free f
  == Free (fmap id fa)         -- By coinductive hypothesis; is this step right?
  == Free fa                   -- Functor f => Functor (Free f), + functor law
```

I've highlighted the step where I'm not sure if I'm doing things right.

If that proof is right, then the proof for the `Free` constructor case of the second law is as follows:

```
fmap f (fmap g (Free fa))
  == fmap f (Free (fmap (fmap g) fa))
  == Free (fmap (fmap f) (fmap (fmap g) fa))
  == Free (fmap (fmap f . fmap g) fa)
  == Free (fmap (fmap (f . g)) fa)           -- By coinductive hypothesis
  == fmap (f . g) (Free fa)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. The 'base case' for the coinduction is the `Pure` constructor, and the induction is over levels of nesting of the `Free` constructor.

The complete proofs are

```
-- 1. First functor law

--   a. Base case

fmap id (Pure a) = Pure (id a) -- Functor instance for Free
                 = Pure a      -- definition of id

--   b. Inductive case

fmap id (Free fa) = Free (fmap (fmap id) fa) -- Functor instance for Free
                  = Free (fmap id fa)        -- coinductive hypothesis
                  = Free fa                  -- 1st functor law for f

-- 2. Second functor law

--   a. Base case

fmap f (fmap g (Pure a)) = fmap f (Pure (g a))   -- Functor instance for Free
                         = Pure (f (g a))        -- Functor instance for Free
                         = Pure ((f . g) a)      -- Definition of (.)
                         = fmap (f . g) (Pure a) -- Functor instance for Free

--   b. Inductive case

fmap f (fmap g (Free fa)) = fmap f (Free (fmap (fmap g) fa))        -- Functor instance for Free
                          = Free (fmap (fmap f) (fmap (fmap g) fa)) -- Functor instance for Free
                          = Free (fmap (fmap f . fmap g) fa)        -- 2nd functor law for f
                          = Free (fmap (fmap (f . g) fa))           -- Coinductive hypothesis
                          = fmap (f . g) (Free fa)                  -- Functor instance for Free
```

Comment: Wait, why is this coinduction instead of just plain boring old induction?

Comment: @DanielWagner If i understand it right, it's because we have cases like `fix (Free . Identity)`, which don't contain `Pure` anywhere...

Comment: @ChrisTaylor Ok, I'm confused a little bit. Why are the (b) cases labeled "Inductive case" if we're using coinduction? Likewise for the "Base case" label on the (a) cases—I thought "base case" implied well-foundedness, and coinduction didn't?

Comment: it is coinduction because it is a coinductive type.  The same argument works with an inductive version of `Free` because you grow the result and shrink the argument in lock step.  Calling it a "base case" though is a little odd.

Comment: I'd expect `Free` to be data, not codata. Not that Haskell keeps such things carefully separated or anything, but that's what we're aiming for, at least.